# React Native show Homepage if is connected

Tags: react-native

How to show React Native Homepage if is connected?
and if is not connected, Show a full screen photo? (with a Condition by `NetInfo`)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NetInfo
} from 'react-native';

function ConnectionOk() {
  return (
    <View >
      <Text >
        Welcome to React Native1!
        </Text>
      <Text >
        To get started, edit App.js
        </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function ConnectionNotOk() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>not Connected ...</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isConnected: false,
      isMounted: true
    };

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // my way of checking internet, don't use both methods
    // this.checkInternetConnection();

    // Its good idea to attach event listener here, or in constructor
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
      'connectionChange',
      this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
    );
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {

    this.setState({
      isMounted: false
    });
    // Its good idea to remove all event listener here
    NetInfo.removeEventListener(
      'connectionChange',
      this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
    );
  };

  checkInternetConnection() {

    fetch("https://httpbin.org/ip")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {

        //update the state only when component is mounted, else it will throw warning
        if (this.state.isMounted) {
          this.setState({
            isConnected: true
          });
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        // No internet, redirect to some action if required

      })
  };

  handleFirstConnectivityChange(isConnected) {

    if (isConnected) {
      this.setState({
        isConnected: true
      });
    } else {
      //redirect to some route if required
      return <ConnectionNotOk />;
    }

    render() {
      return this.state.isConnected ? < ConnectionOk /> : < ConnectionNotOk />
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Use redirect function with react-navigation

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: `this.props.navigation.navigate('Routename')` just a simple function to call inside the constructor

Comment: I mean How to pass `NetInfo.isConnected` , Because i'm geting red screen error when use an if condition with `isConnected`

Comment: If you use expo generate a snap it will be easy to debug!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some flag variable in component state.

From my experience I can say that NetInfo doesn't always gives correct info. ex Internet data is on but no internet connection, NetInfo will return true.

I handle this case by fetching some http api (say https://httpbin.org/ip) which is light and gives correct info about internet.

Also its a good idea to define,add/remove listeners in their appropriate places instead of render.

Try following:

```js
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component < Props > {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isConnected: false,
      isMounted: true
    };
    
    this.checkInternetConnection = this.checkInternetConnection.bind(this);
    this.handleFirstConnectivityChange = this.handleFirstConnectivityChange.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount() {

    // my way of checking internet, don't use both methods
    // this.checkInternetConnection();

    // Its good idea to attach event listener here, or in constructor
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
      'connectionChange',
      this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

    this.setState({
      isMounted: false
    });
    // Its good idea to remove all event listener here
    NetInfo.removeEventListener(
      'connectionChange',
      this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
    );
  }
  checkInternetConnection() {

    fetch("https://httpbin.org/ip")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {

        //update the state only when component is mounted, else it will throw warning
        if (this.state.isMounted) {
          this.setState({
            isConnected: true
          });
        }

      }).catch(err => {
        // No internet, redirect to some action if required

      })
  }


  handleFirstConnectivityChange(isConnected) {
    if (isConnected) {
      this.setState({
        isConnected: true
      });
    } else {

      //redirect to some route if required
      //return <ConnectedNotOk / > ;
    }
  }
  render() {

    return (
      this.state.isConnected ? <ConnectionOk /> : <ConnectionNotOk />
    );

  }
}
```

My full example [code](https://github.com/priyesh9875/Anaadyanta/blob/master/app/components/SyncServer.js).

Comment: I updated My Question,  your render()  block got This error: `[js] ';' expected.`

Comment: Still I have syntax error, Can you please check my question code?

Comment: yes, `}` is missing after `handleFirstConnectivityChange` function. Updated the answer

Comment: I got a red screen error: `undefined is not a function (evaluating this.setState({isConnected:true})`

Comment: the function need to access `this` context, so need to bind them. answer updated

Comment: Thanks Dear Priyesh Kumar Solved ❤️

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

```js
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
      console.log('First, is ' + (isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline'));
    });
    function handleFirstConnectivityChange(isConnected) {
      console.log('Then, is ' + (isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline'));
      if (isConnected == false) {
        // your image
      }
      else{
      Actions.HomePage() //if connected go to homepage
      }
      NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
        'connectionChange',
        handleFirstConnectivityChange
      );
    }
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
      'connectionChange',
      handleFirstConnectivityChange
    );
```

i am using **react-native-router-flux** for redirection

Comment: I Can't  return <ConnectedOk />; in else{} Block and got that red error.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by having isConnected flag in state and using network code set it to true or false dynamically. Then inside the render function use below code
{ this.state.isConnected && 
      // Your UI code here
 }

I have made some changes in your code. Hope it will help you. Please find complete code below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
   Platform,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   View,
   NetInfo
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       isConnected: false,
       isMounted: true
     };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    NetInfo.addEventListener(
      'connectionChange',
      this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     this.setState({
       isMounted: false
     });
     // Its good idea to remove all event listener here
     NetInfo.removeEventListener(
       'connectionChange',
       this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
     );
  }

  handleFirstConnectivityChange(connectionInfo) {
    if(connectionInfo.type && connectionInfo.type != "none"){
      this.setState({
         isConnected: true
      });
    }else {
      this.setState({
         isConnected: false
      });
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.isConnected &&
          <View >
            <Text >
              Welcome to React Native1!
            </Text>
            <Text >
              To get started, edit App.js
            </Text>
          </View>
        }
        {!this.state.isConnected &&
          <View>
            <Text>not Connected ...</Text>
          </View>
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you Have an example to fix my Code and red Error?

Comment: Hi @SedricHeidarizarei , I have updated the answer and added entire code of mine. Please check the same, hope it will help you.